# Facebook Messenger Platform: how to get user specific information?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm trying the recent released Facebook Messenger Platform and so far so good. Everything worked well and I was able to create a echo bot.

But I'm wondering how I could identify this user that started chatting in my page. For example, when a user started chatting I get a PID user (page specific user id).

Making the follow request to Facebook Graph API:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{PAGE_SPECIFIC_USER_ID}
```

I discovered that I can just ask for the following fields: first_name,last_name and profile_pic.

So my question is, how could I discover if this user is a current customer of my business page? Is there another way of querying more information (like e-mail and real facebook user id)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to do this. The best way would be to prompt the user to enter their information in chat or give them a link to a mobile login page or some other way of linking their account to the chat.

Answer (score 6):

Facebook has updated the messenger platform API [(2016-07-01)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/changelog) and introduced a new feature called [Account Linking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking). This can be used to identify a user who has created an account on your website via `Facebook Login` and you can link the two accounts. Facebook login has its own set of permissions which can be used to get a lot more information via Facebook graph API. You can find the complete list [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions).

Answer (score 2):

Messenger Platform 2.0 introduce "ID Matching API" ,that will solve the problem.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts

Answer (score -1):

you can retreive a user information like below using fbmq library https://github.com/conbus/fbmq

```
# this method will occur when a message received from user
@page.handle_message
def message_handler(event):
  user_profile = page.get_user_profile(event.sender_id)
  print(user_profile) #first_name, last_name, profile_pic, gender ...
```